# How to upload image using django raw form

Tags: django, django-forms

Im trying to upload image using django raw form. How do I get image from the form? So that I can assign it to a model and save it? Is there a method like `cleaned_data.get()` for images?

models.py

```
class University(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    about = models.TextField(max_length = 2083)
    facts = models.TextField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True)
    type_of_university = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = UNIVERSITY_TYPE_CHOICES)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'logo', blank=True, null=True)
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'cover_photo', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class UniversityForm(forms.Form):
    name                        = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    about                       = forms.CharField()
    facts                       = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type_of_university          = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UNIVERSITY_TYPE_CHOICES)
    logo                        = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    cover_photo                 = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
class UniversityFormView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        main_form = UniversityForm()
        context = {
            'main_form':main_form
        }
        return render (self.request, 'university/initial_form.html', context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        main_form = UniversityForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        context = {
        'main_form': main_form
        }
        if main_form.is_valid():
            name                = main_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            about               = main_form.cleaned_data.get('about')
            facts               = main_form.cleaned_data.get('facts')
            type_of_university  = main_form.cleaned_data.get('type_of_university')
            logo               = main_form.cleaned_data.get()'logo')
            cover_photo        = main_form.cleaned_data.get('cover_photo')
            university = University(
                user                = self.request.user,
                name                = name,
                about               = about,
                facts               = facts,
                type_of_university  = type_of_university,
                logo                = logo,
                cover_photo         = cover_photo 
            )
            university.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "Form submitted successfully!")
            return redirect('address_form')
        else:
            messages.warning(self.request, "Something went wrong!")
            return redirect('university_form')
        return render (self.request, 'university/initial_form.html', context)
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have defined the models, so you can use model form instead of form

Comment: @bmons Yes, but I don't want to show user field. Is there a way to assign user field to active user in model form without showing it in form?

Comment: as per your model you can assign user to the form with request.user

Comment: How do I do that? Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a model form instead of form and assign user from request.user in views

```
class UniversityCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = University
        # dont have to add user field here
        fields = ['name',
              '-----',
              ]

class EducationCreateView(CreateView):
    model = University
    form_class = UniversityCreateForm
    template_name = 'your.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        valid_data = super(EducationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        return valid_data
```